# Reveal text/link after an action on the page is performed

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reveal hidden text on a page only until a specific action, such as pulling the string on the light bulb to turn the light on, is made?

I've tried looking up "revealing hidden text after an action in html" but unfortunately, I couldn't find exactly what I was looking to do. If anyone could maybe shed a little light on this and possibly help me out, that would be amazing!

```js
const {
  gsap: {
    registerPlugin,
    set,
    to,
    timeline
  },
  MorphSVGPlugin,
  Draggable
} =
window;
registerPlugin(MorphSVGPlugin);

// Used to calculate distance of "tug"
let startX;
let startY;

const AUDIO = {
  CLICK: new Audio('https://assets.codepen.io/605876/click.mp3')
};

const STATE = {
  ON: false
};

const CORD_DURATION = 0.1;

const CORDS = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-scene__cord');
const HIT = document.querySelector('.toggle-scene__hit-spot');
const DUMMY = document.querySelector('.toggle-scene__dummy-cord');
const DUMMY_CORD = document.querySelector('.toggle-scene__dummy-cord line');
const PROXY = document.createElement('div');
// set init position
const ENDX = DUMMY_CORD.getAttribute('x2');
const ENDY = DUMMY_CORD.getAttribute('y2');
const RESET = () => {
  set(PROXY, {
    x: ENDX,
    y: ENDY
  });

};

RESET();

const CORD_TL = timeline({
  paused: true,
  onStart: () => {
    STATE.ON = !STATE.ON;
    set(document.documentElement, {
      '--on': STATE.ON ? 1 : 0
    });
    set([DUMMY, HIT], {
      display: 'none'
    });
    set(CORDS[0], {
      display: 'block'
    });
    AUDIO.CLICK.play();
  },
  onComplete: () => {
    set([DUMMY, HIT], {
      display: 'block'
    });
    set(CORDS[0], {
      display: 'none'
    });
    RESET();
  }
});


for (let i = 1; i < CORDS.length; i++) {
  CORD_TL.add(
    to(CORDS[0], {
      morphSVG: CORDS[i],
      duration: CORD_DURATION,
      repeat: 1,
      yoyo: true
    }));


}

Draggable.create(PROXY, {
  trigger: HIT,
  type: 'x,y',
  onPress: e => {
    startX = e.x;
    startY = e.y;
  },
  onDrag: function() {
    set(DUMMY_CORD, {
      attr: {
        x2: this.x,
        y2: this.y
      }
    });


  },
  onRelease: function(e) {
    const DISTX = Math.abs(e.x - startX);
    const DISTY = Math.abs(e.y - startY);
    const TRAVELLED = Math.sqrt(DISTX * DISTX + DISTY * DISTY);
    to(DUMMY_CORD, {
      attr: {
        x2: ENDX,
        y2: ENDY
      },
      duration: CORD_DURATION,
      onComplete: () => {
        if (TRAVELLED > 50) {
          CORD_TL.restart();
        } else {
          RESET();
        }
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --on: 0;
  --bg: hsl(calc(200 - (var(--on) * 160)), calc((20 + (var(--on) * 50)) * 1%), calc((20 + (var(--on) * 60)) * 1%));
  --cord: hsl(0, 0%, calc((60 - (var(--on) * 50)) * 1%));
  --stroke: hsl(0, 0%, calc((60 - (var(--on) * 50)) * 1%));
  --shine: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, calc(0.75 - (var(--on) * 0.5)));
  --cap: hsl(0, 0%, calc((40 + (var(--on) * 30)) * 1%));
  --filament: hsl(45, calc(var(--on) * 80%), calc((25 + (var(--on) * 75)) * 1%));
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: var(--bg);
}

.toggle-scene {
  overflow: visible !important;
  height: 50vmin;
  position: absolute;
}

.toggle-scene__cord {
  stroke: var(--cord);
  cursor: move;
}

.toggle-scene__cord:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-scene__cord:nth-of-type(2),
.toggle-scene__cord:nth-of-type(3),
.toggle-scene__cord:nth-of-type(4),
.toggle-scene__cord:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-scene__cord-end {
  stroke: var(--cord);
  fill: var(--cord);
}

.toggle-scene__dummy-cord {
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke: var(--cord);
}

.bulb__filament {
  stroke: var(--filament);
}

.bulb__shine {
  stroke: var(--shine);
}

.bulb__flash {
  stroke: #f5e0a3;
  display: none;
}

.bulb__bulb {
  stroke: var(--stroke);
  fill: hsla(calc(180 - (95 * var(--on))), 80%, 80%, calc(0.1 + (0.4 * var(--on))));
}

.bulb__cap {
  fill: var(--cap);
}

.bulb__cap-shine {
  fill: var(--shine);
}

.bulb__cap-outline {
  stroke: var(--stroke);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reveal Classified (GSAP Draggable &amp;&amp; MorphSVG)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <svg class="toggle-scene" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveaspectratio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 197.451 481.081">
  <defs>
    <marker id="e" orient="auto" overflow="visible" refx="0" refy="0">
      <path class="toggle-scene__cord-end" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".2666" d="M.98 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"></path>
    </marker>
    <marker id="d" orient="auto" overflow="visible" refx="0" refy="0">
      <path class="toggle-scene__cord-end" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".2666" d="M.98 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"></path>
    </marker>
    <marker id="c" orient="auto" overflow="visible" refx="0" refy="0">
      <path class="toggle-scene__cord-end" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".2666" d="M.98 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"></path>
    </marker>
    <marker id="b" orient="auto" overflow="visible" refx="0" refy="0">
      <path class="toggle-scene__cord-end" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".2666" d="M.98 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"></path>
    </marker>
    <marker id="a" orient="auto" overflow="visible" refx="0" refy="0">
      <path class="toggle-scene__cord-end" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".2666" d="M.98 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"></path>
    </marker>
    <clippath id="g" clippathunits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4.677" d="M-774.546 827.629s12.917-13.473 29.203-13.412c16.53.062 29.203 13.412 29.203 13.412v53.6s-8.825 16-29.203 16c-21.674 0-29.203-16-29.203-16z"></path>
    </clippath>
    <clippath id="f" clippathunits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M-868.418 945.051c-4.188 73.011 78.255 53.244 150.216 52.941 82.387-.346 98.921-19.444 98.921-47.058 0-27.615-4.788-42.55-73.823-42.55-69.036 0-171.436-30.937-175.314 36.667z"></path>
    </clippath>
  </defs>
  <g class="toggle-scene__cords">
    <path class="toggle-scene__cord" marker-end="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="6" d="M123.228-28.56v150.493" transform="translate(-24.503 256.106)"></path>
    <path class="toggle-scene__cord" marker-end="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="6" d="M123.228-28.59s28 8.131 28 19.506-18.667 13.005-28 19.507c-9.333 6.502-28 8.131-28 19.506s28 19.507 28 19.507" transform="translate(-24.503 256.106)"></path>
    <path class="toggle-scene__cord" marker-end="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="6" d="M123.228-28.575s-20 16.871-20 28.468c0 11.597 13.333 18.978 20 28.468 6.667 9.489 20 16.87 20 28.467 0 11.597-20 28.468-20 28.468" transform="translate(-24.503 256.106)"></path>
    <path class="toggle-scene__cord" marker-end="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="6" d="M123.228-28.569s16 20.623 16 32.782c0 12.16-10.667 21.855-16 32.782-5.333 10.928-16 20.623-16 32.782 0 12.16 16 32.782 16 32.782" transform="translate(-24.503 256.106)"></path>
    <path class="toggle-scene__cord" marker-end="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="6" d="M123.228-28.563s-10 24.647-10 37.623c0 12.977 6.667 25.082 10 37.623 3.333 12.541 10 24.647 10 37.623 0 12.977-10 37.623-10 37.623" transform="translate(-24.503 256.106)"></path>
    <g class="line toggle-scene__dummy-cord">
      <line marker-end="url(#a)" x1="98.7255" x2="98.7255" y1="240.5405" y2="380.5405"></line>
    </g>
    <circle class="toggle-scene__hit-spot" cx="98.7255" cy="380.5405" r="60" fill="transparent"></circle>
  </g>
  <g class="toggle-scene__bulb bulb" transform="translate(844.069 -645.213)">
    <path class="bulb__cap" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4.677" d="M-774.546 827.629s12.917-13.473 29.203-13.412c16.53.062 29.203 13.412 29.203 13.412v53.6s-8.825 16-29.203 16c-21.674 0-29.203-16-29.203-16z"></path>
    <path class="bulb__cap-shine" d="M-778.379 802.873h25.512v118.409h-25.512z" clip-path="url(#g)" transform="matrix(.52452 0 0 .90177 -368.282 82.976)"></path>
    <path class="bulb__cap" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4" d="M-774.546 827.629s12.917-13.473 29.203-13.412c16.53.062 29.203 13.412 29.203 13.412v0s-8.439 10.115-28.817 10.115c-21.673 0-29.59-10.115-29.59-10.115z"></path>
    <path class="bulb__cap-outline" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4.677" d="M-774.546 827.629s12.917-13.473 29.203-13.412c16.53.062 29.203 13.412 29.203 13.412v53.6s-8.825 16-29.203 16c-21.674 0-29.203-16-29.203-16z"></path>
    <g class="bulb__filament" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5">
      <path d="M-752.914 823.875l-8.858-33.06"></path>
      <path d="M-737.772 823.875l8.858-33.06"></path>
    </g>
    <path class="bulb__bulb" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" d="M-783.192 803.855c5.251 8.815 5.295 21.32 13.272 27.774 12.299 8.045 36.46 8.115 49.127 0 7.976-6.454 8.022-18.96 13.273-27.774 3.992-6.7 14.408-19.811 14.408-19.811 8.276-11.539 12.769-24.594 12.769-38.699 0-35.898-29.102-65-65-65-35.899 0-65 29.102-65 65 0 13.667 4.217 26.348 12.405 38.2 0 0 10.754 13.61 14.746 20.31z"></path>
    <circle class="bulb__flash" cx="-745.343" cy="743.939" r="83.725" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="10,30" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="10"></circle>
    <path class="bulb__shine" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="12" d="M-789.19 757.501a45.897 45.897 0 013.915-36.189 45.897 45.897 0 0129.031-21.957"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://assets.codepen.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin3.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/Draggable.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried looking up "revealing hidden text after an action in html" but unfortunately, I couldn't find exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide your code as a [repro] while paying extra attention to the word **minimal**. Note that SO is meant as a repsoitory and as such phrases such as `please help`, `hi`, `thank you` or personale xpressions as `it is pretty cool` are off-topic here.

Comment: Seeing that you are using a full fletched library, I'd say start with going through their [documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/): [eventCallbacks](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween/eventCallback())

Comment: Basically what you need here are custom events and an `addEventListener`. Then `classList` + `add` to ad a class and solve the whole issue at CSS level. However, the bigger issue is the idea itself. While it might sound cool to you on paper it will be a nightmare for users. Drag-pulling a visual string ona screen it not ituitive for msot users and will exclude all users that do not use pc mices and all user that require accessibility.